# commutativity of the operator

Tags: differential-geometry, riemannian-geometry, analytic-geometry, vector-fields, covariance

I am reading an article and I had a big question and wanted to know if colleagues could help me.

If we define an operator $P$ in a Riemannian manifold $(M^n,g)$ as follows:

For each vector field $Z$ in $M$ we have
$$P(X,Y)=g(\nabla_YQ(Z),X),$$ where Q is a symmetric operator and g is Riemannian metric.
Thus, what could you say about the commutativity of this operator, that is, is P symmetric?  anti-symmetrical?  or neither?  thank you so much who can help me.